# Unloading UserForm also unexpectedly closes and unloads all other active forms

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have researched several questions and answers, but was unable to solve my problem.

I have a workbook that when it opens then a UserForm is shown, let's call it the main form.
On the main form there are several controls, one specific checkbox when clicked and it's value is changed to TRUE then it opens another UserForm, let's call this one the secondary form.

This secondary form is a simple password prompt form, and it's code name is pswdPrompt.
The main form code name is usf_TDM.

Now the code inside the pwsdPrompt is the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btn_input_Click()

    Call passwordSubmit
    Me.Hide
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With usf_TDM
        Me.Top = .Top + .Height / 2
        Me.Left = .Left + .Width / 2
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Call closePswdForm
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The called subs `passwordSubmit` and `closePswdForm` are inside a module:

```
Public Sub passwordSubmit()

    Application.enableEvents = False
    With pswdPrompt
        
        If .txt_password.Value = unblockPassword Then
            
            usf_TDM.c_unblockForced.Value = True
            
        Else
            
            usf_TDM.c_unblockForced.Value = False
            
        End If
        
        .txt_password.Value = ""
        
    End With
    Application.enableEvents = True

End Sub

Public Sub closePswdForm()

    pswdPrompt.Hide

End Sub
```

When I get to the `pswdPrompt.Hide` command, the secondary form dissapears BUT after inserting a breakpoint on the QueryClose event of the main form, I discovered that after the secondary form dissapears somehow the code continues to the QueryClose event of the main form even if no code called for the closure of the main form.

Furthermore, upon getting there the CloseMode variable of the event equals 1, which according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-event) it means that "The Unload statement is invoked from code."

However at no point no Unload command was used.
So I'm unable to understand what is going on, and also this disrupt the purpose of the main form also.

Can anyone decipher what is going on here please?

**UPDATE**

After reading through the information, I have changed the code.
But before changing the code, I noticed that the problem I had dissapeared even though the default instances were being used, so I'm thinking it was some other context error.

I have however changed the code to use explicit instances of each user form.
I didn't use encapsulation nor composition as suggested on the rubberduck article because the software I wrote isn't that big and doesn't need to be scalable.

I find myself now with another problem, I have been searching for a way to identify each instance of each user form.
So far, and this is the wrong way to do it, I have been using the `vba.Userforms` with the index.

Is there another way to identify each instance?

Comment: If you're using the "default instance" of your userforms then a good first step might be to revise your code to avoid that.  Eg see https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/ and/or  https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html

Comment: Hello @TimWilliams, I have been reading both pages you sent me, by the way thanks for your comment, this isn't the 1st time you help me here on StackOverflow. I will try to make a new workbook with a main and secondary mock up forms to better undertand what I'm doing wrong and will give an update after learning trying testing and understanding better. Thanks!!